# When is "Catholicism" not "Catholicism"

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/25216/1619), wanting to learn more about the 'Catholic' view of baptism. I initially assumed there was no ambiguity about what perspective I was looking for, but I later edited to make this more explicit:

> To clarify, by tagging the question [catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism), I'm indicating that I'm interested in learning about current mainstream Catholic thought. That of course includes any implications of recent councils such as Vatican II.

The reason I made that edit was because I received [an answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/25241/1619) that in my ignorance I assumed was purporting to be from what I would understand as a Catholic perspective. I think I'm right in saying this was not the case: tucked away in the answer was a clue:

> ... prior to Vatican II, there was never ... In modern times however the concept of Baptism of Desire, which is anathematized ...

If I'm right and this answer is from the perspective of a "Catholic" position that is not mainstream, surely either ...

- It is "not an answer" (and I should flag it)

  or
- It needs a big obvious disclaimer at the top to spell out the actual perspective

... based on the tag wiki for [catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism):

> Catholicism encompasses all churches who hold to the Pope (in Rome) as being the earthly head of the church, along with the attendant structure, mores, values, and teachings thereof. This is mainly the church commonly called the Roman Catholic church, but also a number of much smaller churches
>
> Further information can be found at the helpful Wikipedia article.
>
> Use this tag for all questions about the organization of the Catholic church, its structures and practices and teachings specific to it, and of any other churches that fall within this definition.

So, am I right, or is the burden on me to spell out in more precise terms what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3):

While I also answered the question, I think that the answer to which you refer also offers a valid Catholic perspective, with Papal support (though I disagree with that OP's interpretation of the decrees cited), and as such I think it constitutes a valid answer, useful and worthy of consideration.

It *might* be that a clarification of the perspective would improve the answer, but I am not certain that's necessary.

I would let it be.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask how you interpret the phrase "prior to Vatican II" in the answer? Am I misinterpreting it as something like "Vatican II marks the boundary between the true and apostate Roman papacy"?

Comment: Vatican II was a landmark general council that marks a major shift in Catholic doctrine and theology, that does in a very real sense divide traditional Catholicism from modern. But you have to be aware that not every doctrine is ex-cathera, only a very small number of core doctrines are, so much Catholic doctrine is actually fluid over time.

Comment: After the Council of Trent (the so called counter-reformation), the Second Vatican Council is probably the biggest "reformation" in Catholic history (in my judgement).

Answer (score 3):

Few people are asking questions regarding [Sedevacanteism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19524/what-is-the-endgame-for-sedevacantists/19563#19563), if you wanted the answer Mr. Apocalypse info provided, you should have tagged it with that. I'm not going to create a tag because I think it's dumb. I'd rather create another stackexchange altogether committed to Catholicism where we can have an open debate and not confuse non-Catholics.

On this site, you can't really knock the guy for trying to get his point across.  Unfortunately, it just confuses the issue.  Moderators (none of whom are Catholic) aren't going to take a hard line with answers like that and there aren't enough high rep Catholic users on the site to make a definitive stand on this kind of stuff.

Comment: This question (or rather, answer) got brought up here because I prompted an inquiry. I may not be Catholic but I don't see any sense in misinformation and it seemed like a clarification was in order. If questions actually come up that call for it, a Sedevacanteism tag would be in order.

Comment: I think the take away value from your response is actually that given that this was not tagged sedevacanteism, the answer from that perspective is uncalled for as it was not from the requested perspective. It's that correct?

Comment: @Caleb yep, that's right.  If the answer were not from a sedevacantist perspective, it wouldn't have been so antithetical to baptism by desire, which is pretty clearly stated in the Catechism of the Catholic Church and taught in Catholic Religious Ed. throughout the world.